# A constructible subspace of a Noetherian spectral space is sober

Tags: general-topology

Is a constructible subset of a Noetherian spectral space necessarily sober?

What have I tried: from Lemma 1.2.5 of Sketches of an Elephant (Part C), we know that open subspace of a sober space is sober and a closed subspace of a sober space is sober. Therefore, locally closed subsets of sober spaces are sober.

I also know that a non-constructible subset of a Noetherian spectral space does not have to be sober (https://mathoverflow.net/a/172433/143330).

I also know that any finite subspace of any sober space is sober (because any subspace of a Kolmogorov space is Kolmogorov, and finite Kolmogorov spaces are sober).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and this works for any sober space, not just a Noetherian spectral space.  Since a constructible set is a finite union of locally closed sets, it suffices to prove the following.

**Proposition**: Let $X$ be a $T_0$ space which can be written as a union of finitely many sober subspaces.  Then $X$ is sober.

*Proof*: Let $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ where each $A_i$ is sober, and let $C\subseteq X$ be an irreducible closed subset.  Then $C=\bigcup_i\overline{C\cap A_i}$, so by irreducibility $C=\overline{C\cap A_i}$ for some $i$.  Thus $C\cap A_i$ is also irreducible and thus has a generic point in $A_i$ since $A_i$ is sober.  Since $C\cap A_i$ is dense in $C$, this generic point is also a generic point for $C$.